# libpcap dropped packet detection supported? [Centos 6.6/3.10 kernel/libpcap 1.6.2]

Tags: pcap, libpcap

My application promiscuously sniffs packets (with a compiled packet filter) on an Ethernet interface and I'd like to know if any packets are dropped and not making to my application buffer.

The manpage for pcap_stats is vague and might (or might not) explain the function.

So how do I determine if my particular combination of kernel, distribution, and libpcap supports dropped packet detection?

> The statistics do not behave the same way on all platforms. ps_recv
>   might count packets whether they passed any filter set with
>   pcap_setfilter(3PCAP) or not, or it might count only packets that pass
>   the filter. It also might, or might not, count packets dropped because
>   there was no room in the operating system's buffer when they arrived.
>   ps_drop is not available on all platforms; it is zero on platforms
>   where it's not available. If packet filtering is done in libpcap,
>   rather than in the operating system, it would count packets that don't
>   pass the filter. Both ps_recv and **ps_drop might, or might not, count
>   packets not yet read from the operating system** and thus not yet seen
>   by the application. **ps_ifdrop might, or might not, be implemented**; if
>   it's zero, that might mean that no packets were dropped by the
>   interface, or it might mean that the statistic is unavailable, so it
>   should not be treated as an indication that the interface did not drop
>   any packets.

```
$ uname -a
Linux dvstorblackXS 3.10.80-1.el6.elrepo.i686 #1 SMP Sun Jun 7 08:15:14 EDT 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux


$ ldd *myApplicationBinary*
    libpcap.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1 (0xb76e2000)

$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libpcap.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 774522 Mar  5  2016 /usr/local/lib/libpcap.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Mar  5  2016 /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so -> libpcap.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Mar  5  2016 /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1 -> libpcap.so.1.6.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 572307 Mar  5  2016 /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.6.2

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [comments on the libpcap source](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c#L2089):

```
Reports the number of dropped packets iff the kernel supports
the PACKET_STATISTICS "getsockopt()" argument (2.4 and later
kernels, and 2.2[.x] kernels with Alexey Kuznetzov's turbopacket
patches); otherwise, that information isn't available, and we lie
and report 0 as the count of dropped packets.
```

This seems about `ps_drop` which reports:

```
"ps_drop" counts packets dropped because we ran
out of buffer space.  It doesn't count packets
dropped by the interface driver.  It counts only
packets that passed the filter.
```

`ps_ifdrop` seems to be supported by any kernel versions. It reports:

```
It will return the number
of drops the interface reports in /proc/net/dev,
if that is available.
```

So, you can get the number of dropped packets on your environment by `ps_drop + ps_ifdrop`.

Comment: Thank you for that!